# Php insert no value in primary key MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting values from a form in a MySql table. The problem is when I leave one input field empty (it is a primary key), the db does not complain that the primary key is empty and the row is added to the table with an empty space in the primary key column.

```
 $this->vendor_name = empty($params['name'])? $params['name']:null;
```

So in my case name is empty and I am inserting a NULL in the primary key but there is no warning from the db.

Comment: Your condition is incorrect. It should be `!empty($params['name'])? $params['name']:null;`

Comment: Did you check what value is exactly inserted into database?

Comment: @DarshanMehta thanks you are right. Stupid mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes inserting a NULL value is the right way, but in the code there is a simple condition error, this is the solution:

```
!empty($params['name'])?$params['name']:null;
```

Answer (score 1):

you should make the primary key auto_increment  and not null

try it

CREATE TABLE vendedor(
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have multiple primary keys. In this case only your first primary key cannot be null and must be unique, the others not. So if you want to set your column only for unique values, you can add a unique index.

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table`
ADD UNIQUE INDEX (`column_name`);
```